# Dagger 2 : Pass Qualifiers along without duplicating code

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm struggling with daggers dependency scopes. When I have a chain of scopes I need to manually write a lot of providing methods.
Is it possible to just define how to go from one type to another without appending all these qualifiers again and again?

```java
public static class A {
  public A(String s) {}
}

public static class B {
  public B(A a) {}
}

@Provides @QualifierOne public static String provideForQ1() {
    return "one";
}

@Provides @QualifierTwo public static String provideForQ2() {
    return "two";
}

@Provides @QualifierOne public static A provideAForQ1(@QualifierOne String s) {
    return new A(s);
}

@Provides @QualifierTwo public static A provideAForQ2(@QualifierTwo String s) {
    return new A(s);
}

@Provides @QualifierOne public static B provideBForQ1(@QualifierOne A a) {
  return new B(a);
}

@Provides @QualifierTwo public static B provideBForQ2(@QualifierTwo A a) {
  return new B(a);
}


@Qualifier @Retention(RUNTIME) @interface QualifierOne {}

@Qualifier @Retention(RUNTIME) @interface QualifierTwo {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create similar object graphs for `@QualifierOne B` and `@QualifierTwo B` without exposing their predecessors, I'd favor creating a [`@Subcomponent`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Subcomponent.html) where you use [`@BindsInstance`](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/BindsInstance.html) to vary the `String` inputs and then return the `B`. This way, your subcomponent and its modules represent the object graph of `String`, `A`, and `B` (and potentially which `AImpl` and `BImpl` to use), which also might allow you to use `@Inject` constructors on A and B instead of manual constructor calls.

This should also feel more pure as a DI solution, because then `A` can inject `@ConfigKey String` or `@EndpointServer String`, not `@UsefulForBuildGraphOne String`. You're describing the type of dependency you need, not the build graph into which it is assembled.

```
@Provides @QualifierOne public static B provideQ1B(
    MySubcomponent.Builder builder) {
  return builder.withString("one").build().getB();
}

@Provides @QualifierOne public static B provideQ2B(
    MySubcomponent.Builder builder) {
  return builder.withString("two").build().getB();
}
```

If you give us any more details about what your `String`, `A`, and `B` represent, and which are actually consumed from outside, then that can help determine whether this specific solution is feasible or favorable for you.

See more about subcomponents in the [Dagger 2 User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents.html).